# How to run Spring integration sample in an Eclipse/STS env?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to get https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples to work as expected

I just dont get it.
My env : Linux Mint with Java 8

Steps i've done :
- clone project
- run gralew install
- import project as a maven project

There's no maven libs folder, an no main is runnable..

What do I miss ? Is there a proper doc about this ?

Comment: Try `./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` then 'import existing project'.

Comment: still does not work. no maven libs, no runnable spring boot java application..

Comment: There are no maven deps with that technique - the jars are on the build path. Which sample? Only a few are boot apps.

Comment: i'm trying to test dsl boot apps

Comment: When using `mvn eclipse` you import `General: existing project` not `Maven Existing maven project`. We don't regenerate the poms very often; I just did so and pushed to master and was able to do a maven import of the `cafe-dsl` sample ok. Pull down the latest commit and try again.

Comment: great this work that way. maybe you should add some hints about using samples projects in readme.md ?